# A Widget that retrieves data from a Database

Tags: android, database, widget

I'm trying to make a simple widget that displays texts taken from a database. I have created the database + a button that redirects to the MainActitivy when pressed. However, I can't seem to set the text on the button using my method.

This is a method from my DataBase class to retrieve the first "First name" and "Last name":

```
 public String getData(int i) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = "+ i, null);
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        String firstname = res.getString(1);
        String lastname = res.getString(2);
        buffer.append(firstname);
        buffer.append(" ");
        buffer.append(lastname);
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

It returns a String and I later use it for setting Text on the button with the setCharSequence() method:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

DatabaseHandler myDb;



@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    String result = myDb.getData(1);

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
        views.setCharSequence(R.id.button,"setText",result);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,views);
    }
}


}
```

However, I can't seem to call any method that deals with the class DatabaseHandler in the WidgetProvider class. I have even tried to retrieve the Firstname+Lastname from the MainActivity, then created an instance of the MainActivity class in the WidgetProvider, but it still has errors. Are there any other ways to retrieve data from the database and display it on the Widget button? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

and then on your WidgetProvider class you can simply call create the DatabaseHandler instance by passing the context like:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
```

and then call your getData() method wherever you need.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, I had the Constructor from DatabaseHandler but didnt call it... Thank you!!!